# How can I implement a string split method in Java like c# does

Tags: c#, java, string, split

In C#, if I have a string like this:

```
String test = ";;;;";
String[] split = test.Split(';');
Console.WriteLine(split.Length); // Then I got 5 here
```

But in Java:

```
String test = ";;;;";
String[] split = test.split(";");
System.out.println(split.length); // Then I got only 1 here
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String.split(String,int)](http://bit.ly/Q4E8TJ). SO is not a replacement for JDK documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
  String test = ";;;;";
  String[] split = test.split(";", -1);
  System.out.println(split.length);
```

The [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) explains this method overload that also adds a limit field.

> If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length.

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
test.split(";", -1);
```

This is an unfortunate design decision; by default, `.split()` will trim (most) empty strings from the end of the result array.

If you want a **real** splitter, use Guava's [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v16.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html). It performs much better than the JDK's `.split()` method, is unassuming and doesn't have to use a regex as an argument!